# How to set default argument value in F#?

Tags: f#

Take this function as an example:

```
// Sequence of random numbers
open System

let randomSequence m n = 
    seq { 
        let rng = Random ()
        while true do
            yield rng.Next (m, n)
    }


randomSequence 8 39
```

The `randomSequence` function takes two arguments: `m, n`. This works fine as a normal function. I would like to set the default for `m, n`, for example:

```
(m = 1, n = 100)
```

When there's no arguments given, the function take the default value. Is it possible in F#?

Comment: This is slightly tricky because of currying.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can often [achieve the same effect as overloading with a Discriminated Union](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2013/10/21/replace-overloading-with-discriminated-unions).

Here's a suggestion based on the OP:

```
type Range = Default | Between of int * int

let randomSequence range = 
    let m, n =
        match range with
        | Default -> 1, 100
        | Between (min, max) -> min, max

    seq {
        let rng = new Random()
        while true do
            yield rng.Next(m, n) }
```

Notice the introduction of the `Range` Discriminated Union.

Here are some (FSI) examples of usage:

```
> randomSequence (Between(8, 39)) |> Seq.take 10 |> Seq.toList;;
val it : int list = [11; 20; 36; 30; 35; 16; 38; 17; 9; 29]

> randomSequence Default |> Seq.take 10 |> Seq.toList;;
val it : int list = [98; 31; 29; 73; 3; 75; 17; 99; 36; 25]
```

---

Another option is to change the randomSequence ever so slightly to take a tuple instead of two values:

```
let randomSequence (m, n) = 
    seq {
        let rng = new Random()
        while true do
            yield rng.Next(m, n) }
```

This would allow you to also define a default *value*, like this:

```
let DefaultRange = 1, 100
```

Here are some (FSI) examples of usage:

```
> randomSequence (8, 39) |> Seq.take 10 |> Seq.toList;;
val it : int list = [30; 37; 12; 32; 12; 33; 9; 23; 31; 32]

> randomSequence DefaultRange |> Seq.take 10 |> Seq.toList;;
val it : int list = [72; 2; 55; 88; 21; 96; 57; 46; 56; 7]
```

Comment: To call a function with the type `Between (x, y)` and `Default` is cumbersome; but this is almost the best solution. Thank you!

Comment: @Nick Perhaps it's cumbersome, but sometimes, in my experience, the change to a Discriminated Union can trigger new insights about the domain, and the new Discriminated Union can be used in other functions as well, as [the linked example illustrates](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2013/10/21/replace-overloading-with-discriminated-unions). Anyway, I updated my answer with another alternative.

Comment: Thank you very much. Actually, in Pythoon or R, the usual way to call this function is: (1) `randomSequence(8, 39)`, (2) `randomSequence(39)`, (3) `randomSequence()`. Please note the second call is equvlant to `randomSequence(1, 39)`. And in the third call I didn't specify anything - just empty `()`.

Answer (score 16):

> Optional parameters are permitted only on members [...]

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233213.aspx

So, for your current example, I think it is impossible.
But you could wrap the functionality:

```
type Random =
    static member sequence(?m, ?n) =
        let n = defaultArg n 100
        let rng = new System.Random()
        match m with
        | None -> Seq.initInfinite (fun _ -> rng.Next(1, n))
        | Some(m) -> Seq.initInfinite (fun _ -> rng.Next(m, n))
```

and then use it like this:

```
let randomSequence = Random.sequence(2, 3)
let randomSequence' = Random.sequence(n = 200)
let randomSequence'' = Random.sequence()
```

Explanation: optional parameters can either be fully **Option**al (*m*) or **defaultArg**s (*n*). I like shadowing (reusing the same name) these parameters, but that's debatable.

Answer (score 10):

This seems to be the most elegant solution to this problem:

```
//define this helper function
let (|Default|) defaultValue input =
    defaultArg input defaultValue

//then specify default parameters like this
let compile (Default true optimize) = 
    optimize

//or as the OP asks
let randomSequence (Default 1 m) (Default 100 n) =
  seq { 
      let rng = new System.Random()
      while true do
          yield rng.Next(m,n)
  }
```

Credits:
http://fssnip.net/5z

Answer (score 4):

```
let randomSequence m n= 
    seq { 
    let rng = new Random()
    while true do
        yield rng.Next(m,n)
    }

let randomSequenceWithDefaults() =
    randomSequence 1 100
```

So instead, call `randomSequenceWithDefaults()`