# Is there default parameter in F#?

Tags: f#

I wrote a program to convert file size from bytes to a human readable format in F#:

```
let rec sizeFmt num i =
    let suffix="B"
    let unit = ["";"Ki";"Mi";"Gi";"Ti";"Pi";"Ei";"Zi"]
    match abs num with
        | x when x < 1024.0 -> printfn "%3.1f %s%s" num unit.[i] suffix
        | _ -> sizeFmt (num / 1024.0) (i+1)

let humanReadable n =
    sizeFmt (float n) 0
```

Run example:

```
> humanReadable 33;;
33.0 B
val it : unit = ()
> humanReadable 323379443;;
308.4 MiB
val it : unit = ()
>
```

**Question:**

1. It would be nice if I can set `i=0` as the default value in the
   `sizeFmt` funciton. I checked the F# documentation, only found that
   there's no default parameter. So I have to write a wrapper function
   `humanReadable`. Is there a better way?
2. In order to handle both int and float type input like `humanReadable 123;;` and `humanReadable 123433.33;;`, I have to add a `float n` in the wrapper function. The obvious problem is: it is very easy to exceed the max `int` size which is 2,147,483,647. I guess there might be a better way, are there?

Comment: Do you need, at some point, *forced* depth? E.g., `42,000,000` -> `"41,025.625 KiB"`? Or is it always supposed to be `"40.0543 MiB"`?

Comment: The framework reports file sizes as int64s; that is one "better way".

Comment: @bytebuster It supposed to be: no more than three digits before decimal point + the largest appropriate unit. Eg.: `40.1 MiB`, `438.0 KiB`, `249.8 GiB`. (I used `%3.1f` to format it.)

Comment: @phoog Which framework? Could you give me more information please.

Comment: @Nick the .NET framework.  See [FileInfo.Length](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.length(v=vs.110).aspx) and [FileStream.Length](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.length(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set default argument value in F#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30255271/how-to-set-default-argument-value-in-f)

Answer (score 6):

If `sizeFmt` is only used by `humanReadable`, it makes sense to make it an inner function. That avoids the 'parameter default' issue.

Also, marking the outer function `inline` causes it to accept any type of `n` that supports explicit conversion to `float`.

```
let inline humanReadable n =
    let rec sizeFmt num i =
        let suffix="B"
        let unit = ["";"Ki";"Mi";"Gi";"Ti";"Pi";"Ei";"Zi"]
        match abs num with
            | x when x < 1024.0 -> printfn "%3.1f %s%s" num unit.[i] suffix
            | _ -> sizeFmt (num / 1024.0) (i+1)
    sizeFmt (float n) 0   

humanReadable 123 //works
humanReadable 123433.33 //also works
```

Answer (score 4):

One F# convention that may help is to put primary parameters at the end of the parameter list and secondary parameters first - the opposite of the convention in OO languages. This lets you pipe your primary argument to your function, e.g.

```
let rec sizeFmt i num =
   ...

123.0 |> sizeFmt 0
```

It also lets you easily create partial functions with optional parameters filled in:

```
let humanReadable = sizeFmt 0
```

In answer to 2, no there is no better way, unless you make `sizeFmt` generic and pass in the typed value of `1024.0` but this probably won't make it any simpler.

Answer (score 2):

The only way to have an optional parameter in F# is to use a method instead of a function.  To specify that a parameter is optional, put a `?` before it.  From the documentation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233213.aspx):

```
type DuplexType =
    | Full
    | Half

type Connection(?rate0 : int, ?duplex0 : DuplexType, ?parity0 : bool) =
    let duplex = defaultArg duplex0 Full
    let parity = defaultArg parity0 false 
    let mutable rate = match rate0 with
                        | Some rate1 -> rate1
                        | None -> match duplex with
                                  | Full -> 9600
                                  | Half -> 4800
    do printfn "Baud Rate: %d Duplex: %A Parity: %b" rate duplex parity

let conn1 = Connection(duplex0 = Full)
let conn2 = Connection(duplex0 = Half)
let conn3 = Connection(300, Half, true)
```

Answer (score 0):

Although I know that's not what is being asked about, did you know about F#'s [Units of Measure feature](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233243.aspx)?

```
[<Measure>] type B
[<Measure>] type kB

let bPerKB = 1024.M<B/kB>

let bytesToKiloBytes (bytes : decimal<B>) = bytes / bPerKB
let kiloBytesToBytes (kiloBytes : decimal<kB>) = kiloBytes * bPerKB
```

This gives you a type-safe way to distinguish bytes from kilobytes, and prevents you from accidentally assigning a kilobyte value to a function that expects bytes.

Here are some example conversions:

```
> 1024.M<B> |> bytesToKiloBytes;;
val it : decimal<kB> = 1M
> 1145.M<B> |> bytesToKiloBytes;;
val it : decimal<kB> = 1.1181640625M
> 1.M<kB> |> kiloBytesToBytes;;
val it : decimal<B> = 1024M
```

If you just need the function like above as a quick way to make a large byte value human-readable, this is surely overkill, but if you need to manage byte values on many scales, this may be appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

The existing answers already explain that keeping a wrapper function is a good idea, since this lets the code be as much modular as possible. This would not be very obvious in a simple example, but in real-life projects it would be a great advantage to be able to extend `sizeFmt` at some moment by exposing more parameters — consider that you may occasionally need `"Hertz"` instead of `"Bytes"` (and division by 1000 instead of 1024), or a sting format pattern (five decimal digits), or a *localizable* list of multipliers, and so on.

---

As for the second question, converting to `float`, the solution is very simple: make `value` a [statically-resolved type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd548046.aspx):

```
let inline humanReadable (value:^T) =
    sizeFmt (float value) 0
```

This will make `humanReadable` to have the following type constraint:

```
val inline humanReadable :
  value: ^T -> unit when  ^T : (static member op_Explicit :  ^T -> float)
```

Usage:

```
humanReadable 42424242.42                      // float
humanReadable 4242                             // int
humanReadable 42424242424242424242I            // Numerics.BigInteger
humanReadable (424242424242424242422424N / 5N) // BigRational
```

Using `float` in the *inner* function seems to be fine: any round-off errors will be eliminated by a series of divisions.